# How to specify end of a row when reading csv with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to read a csv file that looks something like this:

```
STATIONS_ID;MESS_DATUM;QN_9;TT_TU;RF_TU;eor
1975;2016032200;    3;   5.9;  89.0;eor
1975;2016032201;    3;   5.5;  86.0;eor
1975;2016032202;    3;   5.4;  87.0;eor
1975;2016032203;    3;   4.7;  90.0;eor
...
```

I use:

```
import pandas as pd
stats = pd.read_csv('data/temp_fuhlsbuettel_akt.txt', sep=';')
```

And the result is:

[image]

The eor column looks annoying and I have to get rid of it with:

```
stats = stats.drop('eor', 1)
```

Is there a better way to read this file without creating the eor column?

Comment: `cols = list(pd.read_csv(data/temp_fuhlsbuettel_akt.txt', sep=';', nrows =1)) df= pd.read_csv('data/temp_fuhlsbuettel_akt.txt', sep=';', usecols =[i for i in cols if i != 'eor'])` ..??

Comment: Why the hack did your producer put a column named `eor` in the CSV??  I've never seen such a thing before.  According to CSV standard rows end at a line break and do not have any other EOR markers.  So I wouldn't expect to have any library support for such a weirdness.  Your solution to drop the column seems the best way to handle this to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`usecols`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) argument, which accepts a list of positional integer indices, or the names of the columns. So either:

```
pd.read_csv('data/temp_fuhlsbuettel_akt.txt', sep=';', usecols=['STATIONS_ID', 'MESS_DATUM', 'QN_9', 'TT_TU', 'RF_TU'])
```

or

```
pd.read_csv('data/temp_fuhlsbuettel_akt.txt', sep=';', usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])  # or usecols=list(range(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
cols = list(pd.read_csv('data/temp_fuhlsbuettel_akt.txt', sep=';', nrows=1)) 
df = pd.read_csv('data/temp_fuhlsbuettel_akt.txt', sep=';', usecols=[i for i in cols if i != 'eor'])
```